# send input array in javascript fetch api to php

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, fetch

I use a fetch javascript script that works perfect, I successfully post variables to the php page.
However when I try to add an array generated by form inputs to the data to post I don't get the values of the array.

The html javascript form with the array:

```
var inputNode = document.createElement("input");
    inputNode.setAttribute('type', 'text');
    inputNode.setAttribute('name', 'pers[]');
    inputNode.setAttribute('id', 'persx');
    inputNode.classList.add('granadainput');
```

The javascript fetch:

```
//The array is nombresgranada
var nombresgranada = document.getElementsByName('pers[]');
   fetch('/pasarelatours/incl-booking.php', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
     'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
     lastInsertId: lastInsertId, language: language, nombresgranada: nombresgranada
    })
   })
   .then(function (response) {
    return response.text();
   })
   .then(function (body) {
    document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = body;
   });
```

Then I receive in php like this:

```
$json_str = file_get_contents('php://input');
$json_obj = json_decode($json_str);
var_dump($json_obj->nombresgranada);
echo print_r($json_obj); echo '</pre>';
```

This is the result I get on printing:

```
var_dump($json_obj->nombresgranada);
prints:
object(stdClass)#3 (2) { ["0"]=> object(stdClass)#4 (1) {   ["_fs"]=> int(1069) } ["1"]=> object(stdClass)#5 (1) { ["_fs"]=>   int(1074) } }
```

And

```
print_r($json_obj);
prints:
stdClass Object
(
    [lastInsertId] => 58
    [language] => en
    [nombresgranada] => stdClass Object
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [_fs] => 1069
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [_fs] => 1074
                )

        )

)
```

The result for the array nombresgranada should be Ana & Peter, not numbers, the other two variables are correct.

Edited and added:
Finally I managed to send the array to php doing this:

```
var nombresgranada = [].slice.call(document.getElementsByName("pers[]")).map(input => input.value);
```

Comment: Can you please add the HTML code in which you have the `pers` id?

Comment: `document.getElementsByName('pers[]')` gets you a NodeList collection, and passing that directly into `JSON.stringify` appears to result in something different than what you want. (Not really surprising, because I wouldn’t know that the JSON serialization of a NodeList should even look like - but expecting it to automagically get the _values_ of form fields is very far fetched.) Loop over the list, get the value from each field and put it into an array, and then pass that array as `nombresgranada`.

Comment: Thanks, I managed to send as array JSON object declaring the variable like this:
var nombresgranada = [].slice.call(document.getElementsByName("pers[]")).map(input => input.value);